# How to compress a zip file

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have code that generates text file(text file can be of greater size) now when user view it, it should download as a compressed zip file. Let me know any suggestion. Below is the code which is working fine but I want compressed zip file.

```
public class filesDB{
    public string str;
    public void outputFiles(){
        str='SALES_FORCE|NAME' + '\n';
        for(OutputFilesDB__c ot : [Select SALES_FORCE__c, NAME FROM OutputDemoFile__c]){
            str+=ot.SALES_FORCE__c + '|' + ot.NAME+ '\n';
        }
        Document d = new Document(); 
        d.Name = '#abc'; 
        d.Body = Blob.valueOf(str); 
        d.ContentType = 'application/zip';
        d.Type = 'txt';
        d.FolderId=UserInfo.getUserId();
        insert d;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, entire force.com model of work (with execution context etc) will not allow you to run long operations with binary data, which is file zipping. You can consider 2 options -- external third party API or creating ZIP in visualforce page using JS

Comment: @kurunve, your comment is a good candidate for an answer.

Comment: Please check this link. It explains a similar use case. http://www.redargyle.com/blog/creating-zip-files-in-salesforce/

Comment: Please do not supplicate the community with claims of urgency. If your problem is urgent, focus your energy on communicating clearly and doing your own research to try to solve the problem while the community ponders what you have shared so far.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is at least one third-party library which can do this for you.

For example, you can check [this one](https://github.com/pdalcol/Zippex#getziparchive)

and use the following code

```
Zippex sampleZip = new Zippex();
sampleZip.addFile('test.txt', Blob.valueOf(str), null);
Blob zipData = sampleZip.getZipArchive();
d.Body = zipData;
```